# C# - If list contains list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I need a condition which is checking for list of string contains all list item of string array.

Example

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "hello", "it", "is", "an", "example"};

string[] array = { "xa","lo","el","t" };
```

So, as you can see each items of **array** exist in **list** items. It does not matter which item of list contains the which item of array. It should just checking for each item of array is contained by any list's item. In this case I should be **true**.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: `array.All(x => list1.Any(z => z.Contains(x)))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array.All(arrayItem => list1.Any(listItem => listItem.Contains(arrayItem)));
```

Comment: @berkan Glad that helped. BTW, if you need case insensitive comparison, you can use `array.All(arrayItem => list1.Any(listItem => listItem.IndexOf(arrayItem, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));`